block-level sort transformation
There are several transform-block operations in Vega that sort the data, but is anything like that possible in Vega-Lite? The sample transform randomizes the order of my data, which is then passed to JavaScript via an expression function. As an optimization I've been assuming that the data is ordered, which breaks after applying sample. As I am accessing the data sources directly (data('...')) I cannot sort within the encoding block. Is there any way to pre-sort during the transform phase so I do not have to constantly sort every time my expression function is called?
Also, interaction becomes very slow once sample triggers and I suspect this may be because the dataset is out-of-order.
